# Spherical coordinates: range choice - best practices & performance

Tags: performance, geometry, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I am writing some code which deals with coordinate systems, geometry and other similar stuff.
I would like to know which is, in general, the most common/practical/efficient way for storing spherical coordinates, regarding common calculations on them.
Is it:

```
theta - [0, 180)
phi - [0, 360)
```

or

```
theta - [-90, 90)
phi - [-180, 180)
```

or something other?

(The above coordinates are expressed in radians for clarity, but I would normally keep them in radians to improve speed, since math functions are usually implemented for radians.)

I know that from a mathematical aspect, it is completely irrelevant, but I am wondering if a certain choice would result in an easier or more efficient implementation.

Comment: What do you mean by "common calculations?" Do you mean stuff like "find the distance between these two points," or "draw these points on the screen," or "find the nearest neighbors of this point"...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. The representations are indeed mathematically equivalent.  Converting from one to the other will cost you a couple of floating point additions, by pi/2 and pi, respectively.  The cost of those additions on common hardware pales in comparison to that of the trigonometry, reverse trig, multiplication/division, and square-root calculations that are common in the arithmetic of sphere geometry.
2. There is a large body of arithmetic text regarding sphere geometry that was developed over the years for dealing with navigation over the earth.  This text often uses the latitude/longitude coordinate system, of -90..+90 and -180..+180, respectively.  To use the well known formulas without conversion, you might want to stick with that coordinate system.